# Same statements, the second not working in different if

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to figure out why a mysqli parepared statement is not working. I can say the page have something like 2 sections, the first one needs $_GET to be empty and the last one needs $_GET['id'] and other to be set (isset). Both "sections" have the same query but in the last section there's a different query first.

Everyting is working fine until the repeated query in the last "section", where nothing is printed.

I have something like this:

```
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {

    if(empty($_GET)) { //first section

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT friends.*, members.*, account_type.* FROM friends  INNER JOIN members ON members.id = friends.friendID
                                                                                                INNER JOIN account_type ON account_type.name = members.acc_type
                                                                                                WHERE friends.userID = ? AND members.acc_type = ?")) {

            $stmt->bind_param('is', $_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['acc_type']);
            $stmt->execute();

        } else echo $mysqli->error;

        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        // php/mysqli stuff working as expected ($row[] printing db data)
        // no need to close
    }

    if(isset($_GET['id'], $_SESSION['user_id'])) { // last section

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        /* prepare statement */
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) rowCount FROM friends WHERE friendID = ? AND userID = ?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $_GET['id'], $_SESSION['user_id']);
            $stmt->execute();
            /* bind variables to prepared statement */
            $stmt->bind_result($rowCount);

            /* fetch values */
            if($stmt->fetch()) {
                if ($rowCount > 0) { // This check is working fine, I tested.
                    $stmt->close();  // close here so no "non-object" error
                    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT friends.*, members.*, account_type.* FROM friends  INNER JOIN members ON members.id = friends.friendID 
                                                                                                        INNER JOIN account_type ON account_type.name = members.acc_type
                                                                                                        WHERE friends.friendID = ? AND members.acc_type = ?");
                    $stmt->bind_param('is', $_GET['id'], $_SESSION['acc_type']);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
                    $row = $result->fetch_array();

                    // Here I have some $row['columns'] and nothing is printed.
                } else{
                    echo $_SESSION['username'], ', you are not allowed to be here.';
                }
            }
            /* close statement */
            $stmt->close();
        }
        /* close connection */
        $mysqli->close();
    }
} else {
        echo 'Please, <a href="login">log in</a>.';
}
```

The first query is working fine, the other is a copy/paste.

I don't see where the problem is :(

Thanks!

Edit: sorry the second query should be "WHERE friends.friendID".

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++) {
    $month = $row['month' . $i];
    if($row[$month] == 1) {
        $paid[] = 'Paid';
    } else {
        $paid[] = 'Not Paid';
    }
    $bonus = $row['bonus'];
}
```

The problem is members.monthx and friends.monthx have the same name, but they are not meant to have the same values so I don't know from what table is getting $row['month' . $i]. The value should be taken from friends.monthx. How do I specify that?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: try `COUNT(*) as rowCount`

Comment: try to use different variable names for the statement as you are using $stmt for both counting and for query. Please avoid that.

Comment: Sorry I'll improve the question.